# Подскажите по маске для регулярного выражения python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Подскажите пожалуйста для python маску регулярного выражения для получения из конфига дескрипшена для xe-3/0/0 и unit 286. Нужно получить это - VPN: OOO (Palatki); R208726
Интерфейсов много, нужно именно из xe-3/0/0 получить.
Пример конфига коммутатора:

```
xe-3/0/0 {
    description "<< 10ge to SW1 port Te2/3; 12.08.2013 >>";
    hierarchical-scheduler;
    flexible-vlan-tagging;
    mtu 9100;
    hold-time up 1000 down 0;
    encapsulation flexible-ethernet-services;
    unit 234 {
        description "## VPN: v1193; via sw1:11/22; 24.10.13 ##";
        bandwidth 2m;
        vlan-id 234;
        family inet {
            filter {
                input profile-id3;
            }
            policer {
                input lim2m;
            }
            address 10.218.0.5/30;
        }
    }
    unit 286 {
        description "## VPN: OOO (Palatki); R208726 ##";
        vlan-id 286;
        family inet {
            mtu 1500;
            filter {
                input profile-id5;
            }
            policer {
                input lim10m;
            }
            address 10.27.2.2/30;
        }
    }
```

Comment: регулярными выражениями? зачем? делайте текстовый поиск по условию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот что-то такое попробуйте

```py
text = """
xe-3/0/0 {
    description "<< 10ge to SW1 port Te2/3; 12.08.2013 >>";
    hierarchical-scheduler;
    flexible-vlan-tagging;
    mtu 9100;
    hold-time up 1000 down 0;
    encapsulation flexible-ethernet-services;
    unit 234 {
        description "## VPN: v1193; via sw1:11/22; 24.10.13 ##";
        bandwidth 2m;
        vlan-id 234;
        family inet {
            filter {
                input profile-id3;
            }
            policer {
                input lim2m;
            }
            address 10.218.0.5/30;
        }
    }
    unit 286 {
        description "## VPN: OOO (Palatki); R208726 ##";
        vlan-id 286;
        family inet {
            mtu 1500;
            filter {
                input profile-id5;
            }
            policer {
                input lim10m;
            }
            address 10.27.2.2/30;
        }
    }

xe-4/0/0 {
    description "<< 10ge to SW1 port Te2/3; 12.08.2013 >>";
    hierarchical-scheduler;
    flexible-vlan-tagging;
    mtu 9100;
    hold-time up 1000 down 0;
    encapsulation flexible-ethernet-services;
    unit 234 {
        description "## VPN: v1193; via sw1:11/22; 24.10.13 ##";
        bandwidth 2m;
        vlan-id 234;
        family inet {
            filter {
                input profile-id3;
            }
            policer {
                input lim2m;
            }
            address 10.218.0.5/30;
        }
    }
    unit 286 {
        description "## VPN: OOO (Palatki); R208726 ##";
        vlan-id 286;
        family inet {
            mtu 1500;
            filter {
                input profile-id5;
            }
            policer {
                input lim10m;
            }
            address 10.27.2.2/30;
        }
    }
xe-3/0/0 {
    description "<< 10ge to SW1 port Te2/3; 12.08.2013 >>";
    hierarchical-scheduler;
    flexible-vlan-tagging;
    mtu 9100;
    hold-time up 1000 down 0;
    encapsulation flexible-ethernet-services;
    unit 234 {
        description "## VPN: v1193; via sw1:11/22; 24.10.13 ##";
        bandwidth 2m;
        vlan-id 234;
        family inet {
            filter {
                input profile-id3;
            }
            policer {
                input lim2m;
            }
            address 10.218.0.5/30;
        }
    }
    unit 286 {
        description "## VPN: OOO (Mullatki); R208788 ##";
        vlan-id 286;
        family inet {
            mtu 1500;
            filter {
                input profile-id5;
            }
            policer {
                input lim10m;
            }
            address 10.27.2.2/30;
        }
    }
"""

import re

print(
    re.findall(
        r'xe-3/0/0 .*?unit 286.*?\".+?(\w.+?) ##\"', text, flags=re.S
    )
)
# ['VPN: OOO (Palatki); R208726', 'VPN: OOO (Mullatki); R208788']
```

Comment: да, оно. Спасибо тебе добрый человек ))))

Comment: ['VPN: OOO (Palatki); R208726', 'yn | fin | rst";\n                }\n                then {\n                    count c109-163-232-108-f;\n                    accept;\n                }\n            }\n            term 21 {\n                from {\n                    source-address {\n                            единственное с мусором цепляет, но если использовать x[0],  то получается то что нужно

Comment: @alex-cherenkov, Так я ж не могу учаесть весь мусор который у Вас там в выводе по одному фрагменту который Вы дали. Естетсвенно возможны нюансы